# why to use rjust when constantly print out the position of the mouse cursor?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Here is the official document about constantly print out the position of the mouse cursor:

```
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

Here is mine which get the incorrect result:

```
import pyautogui
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        print(f'X: {x} Y: {y}', end='')
        print('\r', end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

My Screen resolution is (1920, 1080), with my code ,I may get the mouse cursor coordinate like (X: 498 Y: 93150).

Why this happended? and why should I use rjust()?

Comment: rjust is just used for better formatting of the string. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rjust.htm

Comment: @UliSotschok, is there any fault in my code? My ordinates may out of the screen range，I run this in windows system.

Comment: nothing that I can see. For me everything Looks correct. What do you get when you print: `pyautogui.size()`

Comment: @UliSotschok, when i move the mouse cursor from upper left to lower right, the coordinate looks normal. But when i move from lower right to upper left, the ordinates may out of the screen range. This is the output at some point：X: 284 Y: 92030